# Lighttpd does not take local environment variables from CentOS 7

Tags: http, proxy, environment-variables, fastcgi, lighttpd

I need to pass some local variables to Lighttp from the environment variables of the OS (I am using CentOS 7). These variables are HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY. What I am doing now, is setting those values in the fastcgi.conf file in order to get them, but I want to avoid setting the values there. Instead of that, I want to get that value from the environment variable.

Here is a summarized configuration of lighttpd:

```
fastcgi.server = ( "<file_name>" =>
    (( "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.socket",
        "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/<file_name>",
        "bin-environment" => (
            "HTTP_PROXY" => "<http_proxy:port>",
            "HTTPS_PROXY" => "<https_proxy:port>"
        )
    ))
)
```

I have already set these variables running `export HTTP_PROXY=<http_proxy:port>` and `export HTTPS_PROXY=<https_proxy:port>`.

But it looks like lighttpd does not take those variables so I have to set the values directly in the fastcgi configuration.

**Is there a way that lighttpd takes the values of the those variables instead of setting them in the configuration?**

Answer (score 0):

```
fastcgi.server = ( "<file_name>" =>
    (( "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.socket",
        "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/<file_name>",
        "bin-environment" => (
            "HTTP_PROXY" => env.HTTP_PROXY,
            "HTTPS_PROXY" => env.HTTPS_PROXY
        )
    ))
)
```